# Angular Resolve Bindings Always Undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've just about given up on figuring out what I've done wrong here... No matter what I try my component binding is always undefined even though I can clearly see data coming across.

config:

```
.state('review', {
    resolve: {
        claims: function($stateParams, Review) {
            return Review.getClaims(JSON.parse($stateParams.claims));
        }
    },
    template: '<review-component claims="$resolve.claims"></review-component>',
    url: '/review/{claims}'
});
```

Service:

```
this.getClaims = function(claimIds) {
    return $http.post(path + '/Overpayment/GetClaims', claimIds).then(
        function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }
    )
```

Component:

```
.component('reviewComponent', {
    bindings: {
        claims: '<'
    },
    controller: function(Review, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;
        this.$onInit = function() {
            console.log(vm.claims);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the exact same http call inside the controller and it returns data as expected. However when I move it into the resolve it always returns undefined... Any thoughts?

Comment: can you make a plunker that reproduces this issue ?

Comment: why the dance with `$resolve`? Can you not just directly inject claims into the controller? `controller: function(claims) { ... }`

Comment: I will try that tomorrow @Duncan and post back what results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to take some time away from this but after a long breather I found my issue. In this project I was using an older version of ui.router (0.2.18). There are a lot of projects that use this version where I'm at. When I moved to AngularJs 1.5.x I was testing with a more up to date version but when I tried migrating new my code into a new project I still had the old version referenced as a dependency. I'm now using 0.4.2 and that solved my issue. Thanks.